# Where does nvcc place .o files? They appear in the wrong directory when I compile

Tags: makefile, cuda, nvidia, nvcc

Straight to the point:

I have the following file structure:

- MapA: makefile, main.c, step.cu, step.h, mapB
- mapB: model.cu, model.cuh, model_init.c, model_init.h

I compile this structure with the following makefile, with the command
"**make MODEL=mapB**":

```
MODELDIR := ./$(MODEL)

MODULES := $(MODELDIR)
CFLAGS += -I. $(patsubst %,-I%,$(MODULES))
NVCFLAGS += -I. $(patsubst %,-I%,$(MODULES))

NVCC += nvcc
NVCFLAGS += -arch=sm_30 --ptxas-options=-O1
CFLAGS += -Wall -pedantic
LDLIBS += -lz -lpthread

CFLAGS += -g

SRCS += step.cu $(MODELDIR)/model.cu $(MODELDIR)/model_init.c \
    main.c

OBJS += step.o $(MODELDIR)/model.o $(MODELDIR)/model_init.o


all: .depend runmodel

dims.h: gen_dims.sh
    ./gen_dims.sh 1024 1024

runmodel: ${OBJS} main.o
    ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cu
    ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} -dc $<

.PHONY: depend clean test

depend:
    ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} -M ${SRCS} > .depend

.depend: ${SRCS} makefile dims.h
    ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} -M ${SRCS} > .depend

clean:
    ${RM} ${OBJS} runmodel compare *.cmo *.cmx *.cmi *.o

include .depend
```

This gives an nvlink error, namely " **nvlink fatal   : Could not open input file 'mapB/model.o** "

I looked at where the .o files are placed and my file structure with the .o-files generated with this makefile looks like:

- mapA: makefile, main.c, main.o, step.cu, step.o, step.h, model.o,
  mapB
- mapB: model.cu, model.cuh, model_init.c, model_init.o, model_init.h

Is there anybody that has an idea as to why the model.o file appears in the upper directory instead of in the subfolder, which makes that later on in the compilation process it cannot be found?

A solution to resolve this issue would also be welcomed.

Comment: From which directory is the compiler being invoked? By default, most (all ?) compilers place object files into the *current* directory.

Comment: I don't understand your question. From the look of your Makefile, nvcc is emitting the onject files exactly where you are asking it to.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What version of Make are you using? And what command do you see, when it builds `model.o`?

Comment: @talonmies: Since a makefile does exactly as it is told to, it will be my mistake indeed. But I don't see the rule that states where the onject files should be placed (as is often the case, I inherited this makefile from someone else and modified it a bit). To me it is strange that the onject files produced by nvcc are all placed in mapA, while the ones produced by gcc are placed in the same foler as their c-files. My question would thus be: How do I make that the onject files produced by nvcc are placed in the same folder as their .cu files?

Comment: @njuffa: I have no idea how to see where the compiler is invoked from, but I guess it will be from the mapA folder, as that is where my makefile is situated. My gcc compiler is however somehow invoked from wherever the .c file is situated. I am looking for a way to do the same with my nvcc compiler.

Comment: @Beta: I have no idea how to find my version of Make, but my pc is up to date, so I guess one of the latest stable versions.
The command that I see is: **nvcc -I. -I./mapB -arch=sm_30 --ptxas-options=-O1 -dc mapB/model.cu**

Comment: @Tim That would indicate that the compiler is invoked from `MapA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have nvcc to play with, so I can't be sure, but I suggest you try this, and tell us the result:

```
%.o: %.cu
    ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} -dc $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It compiles and works now. Just a follow-up question: What does the -o $@ actually do? And what is the difference between $< and $^ (the .cu code has $<, but the c-code has $^)?

A reference to the correct manual-page is also fine, but these symbols don't give any results as search queries.

Comment: The `-o` is [a command option for nvcc, specifying the output file](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#file-and-path-specifications). You tell nvcc "-o foo.o", it'll name the output file "foo.o". The variables `$<` and `$^` are two of [Make's automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), where `$^` is the list of the rule's prerequisites, and `$<` is the first member of that list. So if your rule starts with "foo.o: foo.cu bar.h", $^ is "foo.cu bar.h" and $< is "foo.cu".